# How can i replace a specific word in a string in swift?

Tags: string, swift, replace

I am looking for a way to replace a word inside a string in swift. Can anyone help?

this is what I have so far, I can find the specific word, but i do not know how to replace it...

```
     var str = "helo, playgound"

     var findWords = ["helo","playgound"]
     var replaceWords = ["hello","playground"]

extension String {
    var wordList:[String] {
        return "".join(componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.punctuationCharacterSet())).componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    }
}

func stringToArray() -> Array<String> {
    var arr = str.wordList
    return arr
}

func correction(var _arr:Array<String>) -> String{

    for var i = 0; i < _arr.count; i++ {
            if str.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(findWords[i]) != nil {
                println("exists")
        }
      }
  return str
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what your definition of a "word" is. If you're looking for an intelligent built-in notion of a "word", the easiest solution is probably to use NSRegularExpression, which knows where "word" boundaries are:

```
var s = NSMutableString(string:"hello world, go to hell")
let r = NSRegularExpression(
    pattern: "\\bhell\\b",
    options: .CaseInsensitive, error: nil)!
r.replaceMatchesInString(
    s, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0,s.length),
    withTemplate: "heaven")
```

After that, `s` is `"hello world, go to heaven"`, which is the right answer; we replaced the "hell" that is a word, but not the "hell" in "hello". Notice that we are also matching case-insensitively, which seems to be one of your desiderata.

That example shows how do just one pair ("hell" and "heaven") but it is easy to abstract it into a method so that you can do it again and again for further pairs:

```
var str = "helo, playgound"

var findWords = ["helo", "playgound"]
var replaceWords = ["hello", "playground"]

func correct(str:String, orig:String, repl:String) -> String {
    var s = NSMutableString(string:str)
    let r = NSRegularExpression(
        pattern: "\\b\(orig)\\b",
        options: .CaseInsensitive, error: nil)!
    r.replaceMatchesInString(
        s, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0,s.length),
        withTemplate: repl)
    return s
}

for pair in Zip2(findWords,replaceWords) {
    str = correct(str, pair.0, pair.1)
}

str // hello, playground
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! It helped my out a lot! But I have one more question; is it possible to println() what words were replaced? @matt

Comment: @b3rge If you have one more question, _ask_ another question! The comments are not the place for that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably this:

```
let statement = "Swift is hard."
let swiftRange = statement.startIndex..<advance(statement.startIndex, 5)
let newStatement = statement.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(swiftRange, withString: "Objective-C")
// now newStatement = "Objective-C is hard."
```

Following a longer commenting tour: The above is under the assumption of the OP "I can find the specific word, but i do not know how to replace it...", so it's not about finding a "word" which to define is another discussion. It's just about replacing an already found word.

Another word on `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange`: @matt states that this is Cocoa cross-over. In that case Apple is telling a plain lie:
[image]

I fostered the web but there's no Apple source telling anything. Only the Foundation method for NSString. Their Swift book is silent too (in many respects). Well, I don't trust Apple anyway any longer since Yosemite-fail.